# How to reproduce Spring Boot Configuration POJO creation but in Spring Core (No boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

## The Context

As described in the Spring Boot documentation, one of the ways to create a POJO that holds configuration properties values is:

```
//On the configuration class
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {
    POJO_CLASS_HERE.class
})

//On the POJO Class
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "PROPERTIES_PREFIX_HERE")
@ConstructorBinding
```

It works fine - **when you have Spring boot** in the project.

Now, I have another project that has only Spring V4 (core + batch) - **No boot**.

## The Question

How to use/reproduce the Configuration POJO creation of Spring Boot in Spring core ?

[Spring Boot - Type Safe Configuration properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Comment: Unfortunately ConfigurationProperties is part of Spring Boot and cannot be used without Boot. You could create a configuration class that produces an object of the POJO with the configuration. Maybe this article can help you https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: A direct approach is not possible. But Spring Boots is wrapping some functionality of Spring (somewhere). It has to be provided by Spring somehow. I'm trying to research the code in order to understand the abstractions layers Spring boot is using so maybe I can pinpoint where Spring Boots delegates to an Spring Core module the work.

Comment: It doesn't wrap anything in Spring it is a feature build in and for Spring Boot. The only feature used is resource loading and classpath scanning everything else is specific for Spring Boot to this features.

Comment: I've considered the approach mentioned by the article but there is two issues with that: 1- It does not auto bind the properties, you still need to wire them one by one. In the boot side, you only specify a prefix and all props are binded. 2 - using <property-placeholder> will not expose the properties to the Spring Environment, returning null if you call Environment.getProperty() method.

Comment: Why don't you migrate your app to Spring Boot?

Comment: One does not simply enters Mordor my friend. It's not that simple. ;)